# Does Google Cloud Functions charge for warm time after the function finishes?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

If a function runs, it is my understanding that it is kept in a warm state for a period of 10-15 minutes or so to reduce cold starts.

Is this extra time where it is kept warm charged for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default configuration you are only charged for the execution time of your Cloud Functions (and the memory used during that time).

If you [configure a minimum number of instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/min-instances), you will also be charged (at a lower rate, called [idle time](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing)) for instances that are kept warm for you.